how to share one state in different components without knowing the parent React
consider i have a Component called Button it return new button with a state which could be active or not when activated some styling are applied to it
know this Button is an exportable Component it can be used in any place in the project
but i want only one to be active in any time
function Button({startActive,number}) { 
  let [active, setActive] = useState(startActive ?? false)

  return <button className={`${active ? 'active' : ''}`} onClick={_ => setActive(!active)} >{number}</button>
}

function App() {
  return (<>
    <Button startActive={true} number={1} />
    <Button number={2} />
    <Button number={3} />
  </>)
}


now all this code doing is create there buttons the first is active and when i click on one of theme it toggle it
how i can make it remove the active state from all other button
note: don't use the component App if you can i want to be able to use the component Button any where without adding extra states to the parent
sorry if it's easy question I'm new to react

Create a context to hold the active button state and a function to update it.
import React, { useState, useContext, createContext } from 'react';

// Create a context for the active button
const ActiveButtonContext = createContext();

// Create a provider component that holds the active state
function ActiveButtonProvider({ children }) {
  const [activeButton, setActiveButton] = useState(null);

  const toggleActiveButton = (number) => {
    setActiveButton((prevActiveButton) => (prevActiveButton === number ? null :                 number));
  };

  return (
    <ActiveButtonContext.Provider value={{ activeButton, toggleActiveButton }}>
      {children}
    </ActiveButtonContext.Provider>
  );
}

Update the Button component to use the context.
function Button({ number }) {
  const { activeButton, toggleActiveButton } = useContext(ActiveButtonContext);

  const isActive = number === activeButton;
  const handleClick = () => {
    toggleActiveButton(number);
  };

  return (
    <button className={isActive ? 'active' : ''} onClick={handleClick}>
      {number}
    </button>
  );
}

Wrap your button components with the ActiveButtonProvider to provide the context.
function App() {
  return (
    <ActiveButtonProvider>
      <Button number={1} />
      <Button number={2} />
      <Button number={3} />
    </ActiveButtonProvider>
  );
}

Thank you for your time to view my post.
I appreciate your attention and assistance.

how to make it without using the number because it optional

When you provide a prop to a component in javascript, you can make it optional by providing it a default value. For example the number prop could have a default value set to zero.
Function Button((number=0))...
